# Php session variable echos old value

Tags: php

Hello so I have a session_start is inside of my header file which is required in every php file. In my header file I have a cart icon that shows the quantity of items inside of my cart file.

The issue I'm having is that the cart icon doesn't show the current  number of items unless it is refreshed again after the item has been added to cart.

[image]

After Refresh cart and icon both equal 20

[image]

header.php (contains session start)

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x" aria-hidden="true">
<?php 
    echo ($_SESSION['$q']);
?>
</i>
```

cart.php ( require header.php)

```
<?php
    $cart = json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION['cart']));
    $_SESSION['$s'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['$q'] = 0;
    $index = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($cart); $i++)
    { 
        $_SESSION['$s'] += $cart[$i]->price * $cart[$i]->quantity;
        $_SESSION['$q'] += $cart[$i]->quantity; 
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I know I can make the page refresh when the item is added but I would like to stay away from using that.

Comment: PHP can't do it alone I am afraid, you will need javascript I think to auto update the values without refresh, or ajax calls, I guess.

Comment: Mmm alright Ill look into that, time to learn some jquery then haha.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if your adding the products to cart with javascript/ajax or not? If you are, then the page has already rendered so the cart wont change - you either need to manually update the cart quantity with js or do a page refresh.

If you are not using JS to add the product, then chances are you are accessing the sessions in the header before you are updating the new qty in that session

Comment: Im just using php and sql, im guessing that is exactly whats happening. I've echoed out the total quantity on the cart file and it works perfectly. Thanks for clarifying.